# Saving large data from JSON Android

Tags: android, json, large-data

I have an existing app which is using JSON api to retrieve information from the back end server. The way the app works when a user logs into the app it downloads a whole lot of deals and news specific to that user or user groups. Over time what I have found is that more deals and news we add, the longer its taking the user to login.

The code thats taking its time is the read / write the JSON items to the SQLite db on the device. Its takes around 1 min to login a user. Which is a really long time. The code currently goes through a for loop and reads each deals or news and saves it to the DB.

Is there any other way of doing this? I assume there are lot of ways of solving this and been trying to search on the web but havent found a suitable solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the basic structure that all the codes regarding saving from JSON follows

```
JSONObject profileJS = new JSONObject();
if (!jsonResponse.isNull("profile")) {
    profileJS = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("profile");

    ChannelProfile chProfile = new ChannelProfile();

    chProfile.authCode = authenticationToken;

    if (!profileJS.isNull("title")) {
        chProfile.title = profileJS.getString("title");
    }

    if(status_type_id == 4) {
        if (!jsonResponse.isNull("expiredImage")) {
            chProfile.barcode_data = jsonResponse.getString("expiredImage");
        }

        if (!jsonResponse.isNull("cardImage")) {
            chProfile.barcode_type = jsonResponse.getString("cardImage");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!profileJS.isNull("barcode_data")) {
            chProfile.barcode_data = profileJS.getString("barcode_data");
        }

        if (!profileJS.isNull("barcode_type")) {
            chProfile.barcode_type = profileJS.getString("barcode_type");
        }
    }

    if(channelList != null) {
        if(channelList.size() > 0)
        {
            baseDB.updateChannelProfile(chProfile);
        }
        else
        {
            baseDB.saveChannelProfile(chProfile);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        baseDB.saveChannelProfile(chProfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like it's a bad design decision to wait for data to load before the user logs in. Do you have separate calls for deals, news, and login and run each in its own  AsyncTask?

Comment: you can load small amount of data and add a load more option to load rest of data. Let's say you load 5 items first time and next time you load rest data, you can skip the first 5 items and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Will try to implement it that way now. Not sure why i didnt think of that. Great help.